# touchpad not getting disabled while typing on thinkpad E450 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

My touchpad is not getting disabled while typing which is very annoying as it randomly puts my cursor somewhere else while I am typing.

Is there any way/plugin so I can disable touchpad while I am typing

Laptop: Lenovo E450
Ubuntu: 18.04 (It was working on prior versions of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to enable/disable this feature by using `gnome-tweak-tool`. If you need to install the `gnome-tweak-tool`, you could do that through the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then run `tweaks`, navigate to the `Keyboard & Mouse`-section. Under the `touchpad` headline flip the `Disable While Typing` switch to `on`.

---

If this still doesn't work for you, you could add a new file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` and name it something like `90-libinput-quirks.conf` with the following content

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
EndSection
```

The file name itself is somewhat important, it needs to start with a higher number than the `libinput.conf` file bundled with Ubuntu 18.04. Mine was named `40-libinput.conf` so I named mine `90-libinput-quirks.conf` to make sure it was loaded after, and thus overriding/appending, the original config.

Alternatively you could just add the `Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"` to the section `Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"` just as above in the default `40-libinput.conf` file. I'm not sure if the default config file could be overwritten by something like an update, so I prefer the first approach.

Comment: Thank you. Disable while typing was already on but it was still happening, your second solution seems to work, it happened randomly so it was hard to verify if this works, will update if issue persists.

Comment: Great that this does not work like it should by default...

Comment: The "90-libinput-quirks.conf" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: this solution does not work for me. I rather would prefer the synaptics driver, but I cannot remove the  xserver-xorg-input-libinput, even when installing  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.